# Next Js cannot find the svg file in the public folder

Tags: next.js, filepath

I install "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1" and modify next.config.js like this

```
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    PROJECT_ROOT: __dirname,
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    return config;
  },
};
```

So the svg file in the same file as the component imports well.
but Nextjs cannot find the svg file in the public folder.

As far as I know, if there is an arrow.svg file in the public folder, I can **import ArrowSvg from '/arrow.svg'** in the component. But no.
when I use React that path name working well but in Next js, not working!!
error message is

```
./modules/toolbar/components/ToolbarAction.tsx:9:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '/arrow_cursor.svg'
   7 | import PanningIcon from './panning.svg';
   8 | import ShareIcon from './share.svg';
>  9 | import ArrowSvg from '/arrow.svg';
```

Comment: Missed a '.' ? 

`import ArrowSvg from './arrow.svg';` vs `import ArrowSvg from '/arrow.svg';`

Comment: When using `import` you need to use the relative path to the image file. `/arrow.svg` can only be used when setting an image's source path, not with imports.

Comment: What if we use an absolute path for the static images placed inside the public folder and call them via import?